# How to save a link while making a bookmarking website

Tags: php, mysql, regex, hyperlink

I give an ID to a link so that I can easily make stats and show an user what people are talking about a link?

Presently the part in front of ://

But the issue is that, for some sites I can't trim `www` but for other sites I can trim `www`.

Do I need to save the links like `www.example.com` as `example.com` separately?

The Reason Why I can't trim www is here
for some sites like iitm.ac.in don't redirect to www.iitm.ac.in Please check the first link doesnt go to the website but the second goes

Comment: for some sites like iitm.ac.in don't redirect to www.iitm.ac.in Please check the first link doesnt go to the website but the second goes

Comment: @Madhu13 why don't u redirect sites like iitm.ac.in to www.iitm.ac.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you can't assume that `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` have the same content. They could have completely different content.

However, generally I don't think you will find this a problem as many websites will redirect from one form to the other (e.g. ebay.co.uk redirects to www.ebay.co.uk). This means that most users will only bookmark the latter.

Perhaps a realistic modification to your website would be to check that the URL you are saving doesn't redirect somewhere else (301 redirect).